# How do I program the Arduino Primo Core using the Arduino Primo?

Tags: uploading

the Arduino Primo Core website (https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-primo-core) says that I can program the Arduino Primo Core using an Arduino Primo.

I have no idea how to do this!

Can you do it through the Arduino IDE? Which pins on the Arduino Primo Core should I connect to which pins on the Arduino Primo?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

instructions were on arduino.org. it is turned off now, but you can find them in Web Archive (without downloads)
[Arduino.org pages in web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170711122201/http://www.arduino.org/learning/getting-started/getting-started-with-arduino-primo-core)

Answer (score 0):

Juraj's answer answered my question, however I've gone back since and found the link to be broken. Fortunately I saved the file so I'll summarise here for others:

1. Download the nRF52 platform using the Boards Manager:

[image]

2. Connect the Arduino Primo Core to the Arduino Primo using a SWD connector (J2 on Arduino Primo Core and J9 on the Arduino Primo):

[image]

3. Plug the Arduino Primo into the PC using a USB data cable.
4. Select "Arduino Primo Core" from the `Tools > Board` menu:

[image]

5. Select the corresponding port of the Arduino Primo from the `Tools > Port` menu:

[image]

6. Select the `Blink` sketch from the `File > Examples > 1. Basics` menu.
7. Upload the sketch. If the light blinks on the Arduino Primo Core it has worked!